# How to improve this F# function

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am experienced in C# but new to F# and Functional Programming. Now I am trying to implement a class library in F#. Here is one of the functions:
It takes a list of integers <=9 and change consecutive 9 like 9,9,9,9 to 9, 10, 11, 12. For example [9;9;9;1;4;0;1;9;9;9;9] will be changed to [9; 10; 11; 1; 4; 0; 1; 9; 10; 11; 12].

C# function is trivial:

```cs
void ReleaseCap(List<int> items)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        var current = items[i];
        var previous = items[i - 1];
        //If curernt value = 9 and previous >=9, then current value should be previous+1
        if (current == 9 && previous >= 9)
        {
            items[i] = previous + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now is my F# tail recursive one. Instead of loop the List by index, it recursively move item from an initial list to an processed list until everything in the initial list is gone:

```
let releaseCap items =
    let rec loop processed remaining = //tail recursion
        match remaining with
        | [] -> processed //if nothing left, the job is done.
        | current :: rest when current = 9 -> //if current item =9
            match processed with
            // previous value >= 9, then append previous+1 to the processed list
            | previous :: _ when previous >= 9 -> loop (previous+1 :: processed) rest 
            //if previous < 9, the current one should be just 9
            | _ -> loop (current :: processed) rest 
        //otherwise, just put the current value to the processed list
        | current :: rest -> loop (current :: processed) rest 
    loop [] items |> List.rev
```

While the C# version is trivial and intuitive, the F# code is verbose and not as intuitive. Is there any part of the F# code can be improved to make it more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reuse existing functions in order to simplify your code.
Normally when you change items in a list you think of a `map` but in this case you have *something to remember from your previous computation* which should be passed for each item, so you should aim to `fold` related functions.

Here's one: `List.scan`

```
let releaseCap items =
    items
        |> List.scan (fun previous current -> 
            if current = 9 && previous >= 9 then previous + 1
            else current) 0  
        |> List.tail
```

FP is not just about using recursion instead of loops. Recursion is typically used in basic and reusable functions, then by combining those functions you can solve complex problems.

NOTE: You are comparing your C# solution with your F# solution, but did you notice that apart from the language there is an important difference between both solutions? Your C# solution uses mutability.

Comment: For the OP: The [FSharp.Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353413.aspx) documentation is going to be very useful in the context of knowing what pre-existing stuff is out there to manipulate the native collections.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know there is scan function that can do a map with remembering previous state

Answer (score 2):

In your C# code you correctly assume that the 1st element of the list will never change and start with the 2nd element.

If you include this in the F# code you can skip the match on accumulator.
The result will be a bit simpler.

```
   let reduceCap l = 
    let rec reduceCapRec acc l =
        let previous = List.head acc
        match l with
        | x::xs -> 
            if x = 9 && previous >= 9 
            then reduceCapRec ((previous+1) :: acc) xs
            else reduceCapRec (x :: acc) xs
        | [] -> acc

    reduceCapRec [List.head l] (List.tail l)
    |> List.rev
```

(Although Gustavo's solution is still much better - I'm also new to FP)

Answer (score 2):

I thought **fold** was the important one! :-)

So:

```
let list = [9;9;9;1;4;0;1;9;9;9;9] 

let incr acc e =
    match acc, e with
    | h::t, e when e = 9 && h >= 9 -> (h + 1)::acc 
    | _ -> e::acc 


list 
|> List.fold incr []
|> List.rev

//val it : int list = [9; 10; 11; 1; 4; 0; 1; 9; 10; 11; 12]
```